# How python calculate this modulo?

Tags: python, modulo, negative-number

How python calculate mathematically this modulo?

```
>>>-1%10  
9
```

Comment: This is more a math question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519845/modulo-of-a-negative-number

Comment: It is indeed a math question and trying a number less than negative 10 may help: divmod(-11, 10) --> -2, 9 (or -2*10 +9 = -11)

Comment: It looks like you were looknig for the mathematical definition of the modulo operation rather than how python calculates modulo. That's more of a math question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The Wikipedia article on the modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) provides the following constraint for `a % q`:

```
a = nq + r
```

Substituting `a = -1`, `q = 10` and `r = 9`, we see that n must be equal -1.

Plugging in -1 for n:

```
-1 % 10  # Python evaluates this as 9
-1 = n * 10 + r
-1 = -1 * 10 + r
9 = r
```

Testing with another example (again plugging in -1 for n):

```
-7 % 17  # Python evaluates this as 10
-7 = n * 17 + r
-7 = -17 + r
10 = r
```

A third example with a positive numerator and negative denominator:

```
7 % -17  # Python evaluates this as -10
7 = n * (-17) + r
7 = -1 * (-17) + r
7 = 17 + r
-10 = r
```

It appears that when `a` and `q` have different signs, we start with `n = -1` and decrement `n` by 1 until we've found the n closest to zero such that `n*q < a`. We can test this by trying this out with an `a` and `q` such that `|a|` > `|q|`:

```
-100 % 11  # Python evaluates as 10
-100 = n * 11 + r
 ...   -1  # -11 > -100
 ...   -2  # -22 > -100
 ...   -3  ...
 ...   -4  ...
 ...   -5  ...
 ...   -6  ...
 ...   -7  ...
 ...   -8  ...
 ...   -9  # -99 > -100
 -100 = -10 * 11 + r  # -110 < -100
 -100 = -110 + r
 10 = r
```

So while this might not be the algorithm Python actually uses to calculate the modulo, we at least have a useful mental model for reasoning about how a given result was arrived at.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're asking the algorithm that python uses, or why the answer comes out this way.

If the latter, imagine that for modulo `n` you subtract or add `n` until you get a number between `0` and `n-1` inclusive

Answer (score 0):

Its is caluclated like this :-
`-10 / 10 = -1` , 
hence remainder `9`. 
`-10` is greatest multiple of `10` which is less than `-1`.

It is similar to `9 % 5` , will be greatest number less than dividend should be considers.

`5/5 = 1` , hence `4`.

Answer (score 0):

For at least python-2.7.9 it is done by first doing the integer division `x/y` with truncation towards zero. Then the difference of `x` and the quotient multiplied by `y` (ie `x - (x/y)*y`) is calculated. If the result is nonzero and `y` is of different sign then `y` is added to the result.

For example with your example `x=-1` and `y=10`, we first calculate `x/y` which is 0 (-0.1 rounds to 0). The difference then is `-1 - 0` which is `-1`. Now `-1` is non-zero and with different sign than `10`, so we add `10` to it and get `9`.

For python3 (3.4.2) it's a bit more complicated as by python3 the integers are actually `long`s so the [division algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division) is implemented in software rather than hardware, but otherwise basically the same. The division is done as unsigned division using the normal division algorithm using base 2^N for some suitable number `N` depending on platform.